# Querying for excluded rows

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table where I want to select the rows outside the 100 latest (`order by timestamp desc limit 100`) and delete them. Of course my first preference is to simply query for them directly but I don't think that's possible.

1. So my first attempt was to return the IDs of the 100 latest rows in a subquery and use that as part of my parent query. That generated a weird error saying such an operation wasn't supported:

[MySQL subquery restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html)

2. I found a hack where I could wrap the subquery in a "select * from (...) foo" (and it worked), but I don't know how to model that in SQLalchemy.
3. I tried to recursively inner join two instances of the same table having one of them referenced with an alias, but based on the SQLalchemy examples I saw, I don't know how to apply the limit to the alias.

This is my attempt at trying to use method #1:

NOTE: query1 selects ids from 100 latest rows; query3 selects ids excluded from query1 for deletion from query2.

`

```
def rs_tagged_repos():
    return main.session.query(main.TaggedRepos)
...
query1 = rs_tagged_repos()\
    .with_entities(main.TaggedRepos.id)\
    .filter(main.and_
        (
              main.TaggedRepos.status == 'True'
            , main.TaggedRepos.repoID == _repo['repo_id']
            , main.TaggedRepos.scID == _repo['sc_id']
            , main.TaggedRepos.category == _this_tag['category']
        )
    )\
    .order_by(main.TaggedRepos.timestamp.desc())\
    .limit(100)

query2 = rs_tagged_repos() \
    .filter(main.and_
        (
              main.TaggedRepos.status == 'True'
            , main.TaggedRepos.repoID == _repo['repo_id']
            , main.TaggedRepos.scID == _repo['sc_id']
            , main.TaggedRepos.category == _this_tag['category']
        )
    )

query3 = rs_tagged_repos()\
    .filter(
        ~main.TaggedRepos.id.in_(select0)
    )\
    .delete()
```

`

Like I said I'd definitely love to know of a way to directly do this, but at this point I just need something that works. Appreciative of any actionable help.

- Joe

Comment: *I don't think that's possible* why not?

Comment: Every solution I've come up with in native SQL or seen online has been one of the three I've listed or very similar to them. And assuming the ideal solution I've already described is out there, I can't imagine how I'd implement it in SQLalchemy.

Comment: Well see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query, and consider pretending that it's 'outside the latest 5', for the sake of argument.

Comment: It looks like a meta question; I don't see anything re: a specific technical issue.

Comment: Well, that's your loss. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can use `.slice(x, y)` to directly query for my set. I just have to make sure my limit (y) is some arbitrarily large number.

It behaves just like when you use "limit y offset x".

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.slice